# Why I get no error when I use Record string with a number value?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I use `Record<string, MyUser>` and the key of the object is a number. Why I get no error because I set `Record<string>`?

```js
interface MyUser {
  name: string;
  id: number;
  email?: string;
}

const user = (users: MyUser[]): Record<string, MyUser> => {
  return users.reduce((a, v) => {
    return {
      ...a,
      [v.id]: v
    }
  }, {});
};
 
  const find = () => {
    console.log(user([{
      id: 2,
      name: 'Hosa',
      email: 'saas@asa.com'
    }, { id: 2, name: 'Hsasa', email: 'ASDSDA@asa.da' }]))
  };
```

Comment: No, it's not because of `Record`, Both `number` and `string` are accepted as index signature parameter types.

Comment: String index signatures accept both `number` and `symbol` keys, see [the TS2.9 release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#support-number-and-symbol-named-properties-with-keyof-and-mapped-types).  Should I write this up as an answer, or am I missing something about the question?